# Integrate google maps autocomplete with jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

I want to integrate my jQuery Autocomplete field with google maps. So that the field brings up results from my predefined array and it resolves to google maps at the same time.

My code:

```
var autocompleteService = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
var autocompleteList = [];
var eventsList = ["event1","event2"];

$("#edtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: eventsList
}).on("autocompleteopen",function(event){
        autocompleteList = eventsList.slice(0);

        autocompleteService.getQueryPredictions({input: $(this).val()},
        function(predictions, status){
            if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                console.log(status);
                return;
            }

            for (var k = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[k]; ++k)
            {
                prediction = String(prediction.description).replace(/,/g,"");
                autocompleteList.push(prediction);
            }

            $("#edtSearch").autocomplete({
                source: autocompleteList
            });
            $("#edtSearch").autocomplete("search");
            console.log(autocompleteList);
        });
});
```

html:

```
<input id="edtSearch" type="text" size="50" />
```

Now this code works, but because "autocompleteopen" and "autocomplete("search")" call the same thing, I get a repeating loop for the action and eventually "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT " in the console.
My question is, how do I correctly bind the event so that they don't call each other recursively? I've tried using

```
var edtSearch = document.getElementById("edtSearch");
edtSearch.addEventListener("keypress",function(){});
```

and similiar solutions but the error I get is "Uncaught Error: Missing parameter. You must specify input".
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `input` parameter in the `getQueryPredictions` call in your case was either undefined, null or empty string.

To fix this, you would check whether the value to `input` (`$(this).val()` in your case) has some characters.